# How to make URL active and selectable?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS code on [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/OXLRgL):

```css
#burgerMenu {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     top: 52px;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 450px;
     color: #fff;
     background: #2a2e2f;
     z-index: 999;
     transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);

     -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
             transform: translateY(-100%);
 }

 #burgerMenu ul {
     margin: 5px;
     padding-left: 0;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: left;
     font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 400;
 }

 #burgerMenu > ul > li {
     display: block;
     margin: 0 10px;
     padding: 4px 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #444748;
     font-size: 14px;
     line-height: 1.5rem;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
```

**How do I make the URL active when selected?**

I have tried several variations of `:active` without success.

The URL is properly echoed on `mouseover`. I just cannot trigger the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using the `:focus` pseudo-class to open the menu. But when you click on a link inside the menu, the *menu button loses focus*. Without focus, the `:focus` rule doesn't apply and the menu closes.

So `:active` *would work* for links inside the menu, but as soon as the user clicks on a link, the menu itself closes, so you don't get to see it working.

As I see it, you have two options right now:

1. Use JavaScript to open the menu, so you don't depend on the focus of the button.
2. Use [The Checkbox Hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/), which is a CSS-only approach (slightly more complicated and less recommended than the JS option).

You'll be free to use `:active` as much as you want in both of those options.